# constrain coefficients for segmented piecewise linear fit

Tags: r, lm

I am trying to fit data to a piecewise linear model.  The segmented package works really well except I cant find a way to apply constraints to the coefficients.  I need to constrain the slopes of the linear segments to a range of values (e.g. 0-0.1 for segment 1, and >0.5 for segment 2).  Here is an example without constraints.  Thanks.

```
library(segmented)

#generate data for fit
c <- 1 
m <- 0.47 #slope of 2nd line
d <- 4
n<- 30
sd <- 0.2
b <- c-m*d
x<- runif(n,0,10)
y<- ifelse(x<=d,c+rnorm(n,0,sd),m*x+b+rnorm(n,0,sd)) #piecewise data for fit
plot(x,y)

lin.mod <- lm(y~x)
segmented.mod <- segmented(lin.mod, seg.Z = ~x, psi=6)
summary(segmented.mod)
plot(segmented.mod, add=T)
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the elegant way to do this but I managed a solution with constrOptim.

```
#generate data for fit
set.seed(2)
c <- 1 
m <- 0.47 #slope of 2nd line
d <- 4
n<- 30
sd <- 0.2
b <- c-m*d
x<- runif(n,0,10)
y<- ifelse(x<=d,c+rnorm(n,0,sd),m*x+b+rnorm(n,0,sd)) #piecewise data for fit
plot(x,y)

#define slope value constriants
l.slope.min <- 0
l.slope.max <- 0.1
r.slope.min <- 0.5
r.slope.max <- 0.99

# par[1] - transition point for pieces.
# par[2] - slope of left piece.
# par[3] - intercept of left piece.
# par[4] - slope of right piece.
# the intercept of the right piece is par[1]*(par[2]-par[4])+par[3]
f <- function (x,par) {ifelse(x<par[1],par[2]*x+par[3],par[4]*x+(par[1]*(par[2]-par[4])+par[3]))}
r2 <- function(data,par) {with(data, sum(((y-f(x,par))^2)))}

#to set up the constraint matrix and vector follow instructions in constrOptim documentation
ui <- cbind(c(0,0,0,0),c(-1,1,0,0),c(0,0,0,0),c(0,0,1,-1))
ci <- c(-l.slope.max,l.slope.min,r.slope.min,-r.slope.max)
ci <- ci - 1e-6 #displace startinng point from boundry
par <- c(5, 0.05,1.2, 0.8 ) #initial parameters

(ui %*% par)-ci >=0 #confirm that starting values are in the feasible region

result <-constrOptim(theta =par, f=r2 , grad= NULL, ui=ui, ci=ci,data = data.frame(x,y))

abline(a = result$par[3], b = result$par[2], col = "red")
abline(a = result$par[1]*(result$par[2]-result$par[4])+result$par[3], b = result$par[4], col = "blue")
```